# django redirect to subdomain with exact same url

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Django website accessible at [codewithbishal.com](https://codewithbishal.com). This is basically a django blog website and all the blog articles are accessible at `codewithbishal.com/example/<path>`

But now I want to completely restructure the website{such that it is accessible at `blog.codewithbishal.com/<path>`} and I do no want to lose the current SEO therefore I want to configure django redirect such that when someone launches `codewithbishal.com/example/<path>` through google search search result or directly through link, they are redirected to `blog.codewithbishal.com/<path>` instead of a 404 page and eventually google will start showing the new links instead of old once.

Update: Should I configure redirect through apache .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Django redirects](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/08/11/django-tip-21-redirects-app.html) app. Just click the link and find the guide.

Comment: is there a way to automatically configure redirects?

Comment: What is your definition of automatic redirect?

Comment: like I don't need to manually configure redirect for each page

Comment: Not currently. It makes sense to let you chose how to reroute the redirects, think about it. Its simple enough that you can set it from the Djago admin.